# The ethical one

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

Here is a sequence of eight entries in total. I, T ,E and H are given as you can see but what should replace the question marks...

### ??ITEH??

---

Once you've figured out how to approach this puzzle, tell me the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the question says

> what should replace the queston marks

so apply this to give

> **WHITEHAT** - which is an ethical person e.g. a well-meaning hacker.

Comment: Okay yeah, that makes more sense than my answer for sure

Comment: Well done! Hats off ;)

Answer (score 4):

This might be a wild thought but

> The questions marks have to be replace with **1A** and **CL**. That way it spells out "Ethical 1" going from the middle and alternating between left and right as you go outwards.

Comment: Nice attempt, but not the intended answer (given by Tom)